# Wave cone of the curl operator

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, measure-theory, reference-request

How can one compute the wave cone $\Lambda_{\mathcal A}$, defined as 
\begin{equation*} 
\Lambda_{\mathcal A}:=\bigcup_{|\xi|=1} \ker \mathbb A^k(\xi) \qquad\textrm{with}\qquad \mathbb A^k(\xi)= (2\pi i)^{k} \sum_{|\alpha|\le k}A_{\alpha}\xi^{\alpha},
\end{equation*}

of the (row-wise) curl operator such that for every $M \in \mathbb R^{M \times N}$, $$\mathcal A (M) = \operatorname{curl} (M).$$

The result is

> $$\Lambda_{\mathcal A} = \bigcup_{\xi \in \S^{d-1}} \ker \mathbb A(\xi) = \left\{a \otimes \xi \in \mathbb R^{M \times N}:\, a \in \mathbb R^M,\, \xi \in \mathbb S^{N-1}\right\}.
> $$

How does one prove it?